# select sibling and parent divs for javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, children, parents

hi just a general question. When making a javascript/jquery what would be the easiest way to indivate a particualr sibling div, or parent div, with a particular class.

The scenario is sometihng like this

```
<div class="a">
<div class="b"> </div>
<div class="c">
<div class="d"> </div> 
</div>
</div>
```

i would like to make clicking on div class b open div class c. I would also like to make clicking on div class d close div class c. div class b is a sibling div to div class c and div class c and div class c is a parent of div class d.

it is important that the javascript reffers to their parents or siblings  because div class a (the container) will be repeated many times and each different instance of div class b and d should open different divs onclick, instead of all opening all instances with div class c.

so far i have thought of using something like an

```
event.target.getElementsByTagName("div")[]
```

- but actually i think this only looks for children of a particular div which really isnt what i want because im looking for indicating a sibling and a parent. anyone who knows how to do this who could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the sibling via jQuery's `.sibling()` method:

```
$(.b).click(function () {
  $(this).siblings('.c').addClass('open');
});
```

For more precise sibling selection you can use `.prev('.c')` or `.next('.c')`.

There is also a [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) represented by the tilde `~`:

```
$('.b ~ .c');
// or
document.querySelectorAll('.b ~ .c');
```

For closing `.c` when clicked on `.d` I would rely on event bubbling:

```
$('.c').on('click', function (e) {
  if ($(e.target).is('.d')) $(this).removeClass('open');
});
```

Comment: thank you this solved my problem perfectly and thank you for the many different options and explanation

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using jquery's .parent() function?

```
$('div.d').parent().click(function(){
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```